# Passing Date From querystring to Django view

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui

I am passing date from my template to Django view. I am using jquery-ui datepicker. The format I see on console is like this.

If I send `'05-01-2014'` the format is like `'05%2F01%2F2014'`

In my view I have

```
dataFrom = request.GET.get('dataFrom', 'default')
dataTo = request.GET.get('dateTo', 'default')
results.filter(date__range=[dataFrom,dataTo ])
```

but I am not getting any result.My question is how to correctly format date so I get the result?

Answer (score 2):

The URL and its parameters are encoded, you need to decode them to get back characters:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote('05%2F01%2F2014')
'05/01/2014'

# Python 3
>> from urllib.parse import unquote
>>> unquote('05%2F01%2F2014')
'05/01/2014'
```

As you can see, you have slashes here instead of dash `-`, you might need to transform this to get a valid queryset.

Comment: dataFrom = datetime.strptime(dataFrom , '%d/%m/%Y')